# Error using Pillow: ImportError: cannot import name _imaging

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've read the answers for similar questions but none of them seem to work for my situation. 
When trying to use Pillow, I get this error:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 63, in <module>
 from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

In my /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory I have one PIL directory which contains the Image module and then I have PIllow-master directory which contains _imaging.c, so I don't understand why in Image.py line 63 says to import _imaging from PIL. 
I've tried also to cut _imaging.c from Pillow-master and paste it in PIL but it doesn't work.
When trying to import Image, I'm into PIL. 
If I try to import it while I'm into site-packages it doesn't work and says "no module named PIL".

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I have encountered the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your PIL library and install new by:

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Comment: I already installed Pillow, are you sure I should install PIL too? I read that they cannot coexist..
Anyway if I try your command I get this error: 'Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_v/6sd72pcd26j8nd87vmmmtznc0000gn/T/pip_build_MYACCOUNT/PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/MYACCOUNT/.pip/pip.log'

Comment: @Mikhaylova, I am not using Pillow, only PIL.