# Pillow import error from _imaging.so / libjpeg.8.dylib on OSX

Tags: python, python-import, python-imaging-library

I've used Pillow in the past on OSX without problems, however I now get the following error.

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 61, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2):     Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728468/osx-pillow-incompatible-library-version-libtiff-5-dylib-libjpeg-8-dylib) question which appears to be a similar problem but I don't think I installed Pillow with brew.

I've also tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503961/error-using-pillow-importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging) question but the command

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

dosent seem to work and I get an error (no such option: --allow-unverified)

Lastly, I've tried to recreate the [symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187742/python-cannot-import-opencv-because-it-cant-find-libjpeg-8-dylib) to libjpeg.8.dylib but that also did not make any difference.

Would anyone know how to fix this error? Do I need to do something to relink _image.so aswell as libjpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Python PIL was deprecated eons ago and you should not attempt to use it anymore.

What you want is `python[23] -m pip install Pillow`

PS. Using pip command will be deprecated soon because of confusions regarding python interpreters, instead of calling `pip ...` everyone should use only `python -m pip ...` which assures that is calling the right interpreter.