# Pyinstaller with PIL. ImportError: cannot import name _imaging

Tags: build, pyinstaller, python-imaging-library

I am having trouble running a compiled executable that includes pillow. I have used pyinstaller which seems to compile well enough, however after running the exe, an error is thrown. Seems there is a conflict with '_imaging' being referenced instead of 'Image'.

First off, I find it strange how pillow installs to a PIL directory rather than a pillow and the modules are also referenced as PIL. I doubt that has anything to do with the problem though.

There isn't actually a _imaging.py file in Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL however and I suspect this might be a problem as somehow pyinstaller has made the executable require it. Not sure if there is some way to exclude it from the build. This may be a next step.

Issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203575/import-error-when-running-pyinstaller-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503961/error-using-pillow-importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging)have been raised but not solved. Some also refer to PIL not being uninstalled before installing pillow, but PIL is definitely uninstalled and I have tried both binaries and pip installs of pillow.

Any suggestions?

Error from runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\PIL.PngImagePlugin", line 40, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\GISdev\build\gis_helper2\out00-PYZ.pyz\PIL.Image", line 63, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

Extract from the PIL.Image file is below and the offending line is

from PIL import _imaging as core

```
try:
    # If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
    # Note that other modules should not refer to _imaging directly;
    # import Image and use the Image.core variable instead.
    # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
    # and should be considered private and subject to change.
    from PIL import _imaging as core
    if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
        raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "
                          " version of Pillow or PIL")

from PIL import Image
```

And this is how I am calling pillow from my script:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Are you using the latest _PyInstaller_ version? Do you have the file `hooks/hook-PIL.Image.py` under your _PyInstaller_ installation directory?

Comment: Yes, Pyinstaller v 2.1

I do have the hooks/hook-PIL.Image.py. It looks suspiciously empty. Aside from the comments, it only contains one line of code:

from PyInstaller.hooks.shared_PIL_Image import *

Comment: Try updating its content to [its latest version as listed on the official _PyInstaller_ repository](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/python3/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-PIL.Image.py).

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt't work and resulted in the same error as the one above. Any other suggestions? I appear to have the latest version of pyinstaller. I have the feeling this is a fairly simple mismatch between _image and pillow. Can't quite put my finger on it though.

Comment: I have another idea. Please review [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32762148/3903832)...

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. However, after uninstalling pillow and installing PIL, the issue seems to have been fixed.